# Programatically convert yaml string to ConfigurationProperties with Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a third party library which provides a class used for ConfigurationProperties, such as the following:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
public class AnimalProperties {

    private List<Treats> treats = new ArrayList<>();
...
}
```

In Spring Boot 2, what is the easiest way to bind a Yaml string (constructed programatically) to an instance of AnimalProperties? For example, given the string:

```
treats:
  -
    name: treat1
    flavour: sweet
  -
    name: treat2
    flavour: sour
```

In Spring Boot 1.x this could be done using the YamlConfigurationFactory, however this is no longer present in Spring Boot 2.

For example:

```
    YamlConfigurationFactory<AnimalProperties> animalConfigFactory = new YamlConfigurationFactory<>(
            AnimalProperties.class);
    animalConfigFactory.setYaml("{ treats: " + treatYalm + " }");
    try {
        animalConfigFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        treats.addAll(animalConfigFactory.getObject().getTreats());
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct replacement for `YamlConfigurationFactory` in Spring Boot 2.x. In fact, from looking at the source, it doesn't appear that `YamlConfigurationFactory` is actually used any where internally in Spring Boot, at least from my research.

However `YamlConfigurationFactory` internally just uses `snakeyaml`, so maybe something like:

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
String myYamlString = "...."
AnimalProperties animalProps = yaml.loadAs(myYamlString, AnimalProperties.class)
```

Really the only downside is that you lose the validation that was performed by `afterPropertiesSet` that comes from implementing the `InitializingBean` interface.

---

If that yml string is just defined in your `application.yml` as:

```
foo:
  treats:
    -
      name: treat1
      flavour: sweet
    -
      name: treat2
      flavour: sour
```

then you can just inject it as with any bean:

```
@Service
public class ExampleService {
    private final AnimalProperties animalProperties;

    public ExampleService(AnimalProperties animalProperties) {
        this.animalProperties = animalProperties;
    }
}
```

Spring will do bean validation at start-up when the `AnimalProperties` gets created.

Comment: Yeah, whether i had to use SnakeYaml directly or whether there was a SpringBoot2 abstraction was the essence of my question. Using Snake directly does the trick. Thanks!